# Using BeautifulSoup4 to retrieve text between 2 tags at different levels

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here's a snippet of a "real-world" HTML file I'm trying to scrape with BeautifulSoup4 (Python 3) using the `xml` parser (the other parsers don't work with the kind of dirty html files I'm working with):

```
<html>
    <p> Hello </p>
    <a name='One'>Item One</a>
    <p> Text that I would like to scrape. </p>
    <p> More text I would like to scrape.
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a name='Two'>Item Two</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        A bunch of text that shouldn't be scraped.
        More text.
        And more text.
    </p>
</html>
```

My goal is to scrape all the text sitting between `<a name='One'>Item One</a>` and `<a name='Two'>Item Two</a>` without scraping the 3 lines of text in the last `<p>`.

I've attempted trying to traverse from the first `<a>` tag using the `find_next()` function and then invoking `get_text()`, but what happens when I hit the last `<p>` is that the text at the end also gets scraped, which isn't what I want.

Sample code:

```
tag_one = soup.find('a', {'name': 'One'})
tag_two = soup.find('a', {'name': 'Two'})
found = False
tag = tag_one
while found == False:
    tag = tag.find_next()
    if tag == tag_two:
        found = True
    print(tag.get_text())
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a more robust way:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'xml')
tag_one = soup.find('a', {'name': 'One'})
tag_two = soup.find('a', {'name': 'Two'})

for tag in tag_one.next_elements:
    if type(tag) is not bs4.element.Tag:
        print(tag)
    if tag is tag_two:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`find_all_next`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method to iterate over the next tags, and get a list of strings for each tag with the [`strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) generator.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'xml')
tag_one = soup.find('a', {'name': 'One'})
tag_two = soup.find('a', {'name': 'Two'})
text = None

for tag in tag_one.find_all_next():
    if tag is tag_two:
        break
    strings = list(tag.stripped_strings)
    if strings and strings[0] != text:
        text = strings[0]
        print(text)
```